# GStreamer and RTSP stream

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp, gstreamer-1.0, gst-launch, gst-launch-1.0

I'm trying to view an rtsp stream trough gstreamer but when i run this command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://admin:@192.168.1.27:554/ch0_0.264 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw ! autovideosink
```

it blocks here and doesn't display anything.

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Progress: (open) Opening Stream
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Prerolled, waiting for progress to finish...
Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtsp://admin:@192.168.1.27:554/ch0_0.264
Progress: (open) Retrieving server options
Progress: (open) Retrieving media info
Progress: (request) SETUP stream 0
Progress: (request) SETUP stream 1
Progress: (open) Opened Stream
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
Progress: (request) Sent PLAY request
Redistribute latency...
```

I'm new to gstreamer. Can someone hepl me with that?
Thanks in advice.

Comment: You need something like `decodebin` between `rtspsrc` and `videoconvert`

Comment: Thanks it was really helpful!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `decodebin` I found out that the H264 decoder was missing so I solved it by installing the package gst-libav